# Violating the one definition rule by simply linking dynamically

Tags: c++, linux, elf, std, one-definition-rule

**Question:** Are dynamically linked C++ programs on ELF platforms always on the brink of producing undefined behavior by violating the one definition rule?

**More specific:** By simply writing a shared library exposing one function

```
#include <string>
int __attribute__((visibility("default"))) combined_length(const char *s,
                                                           const char *t)
{
    const std::string t1(t);
    const std::string u(s + t1);
    return u.length();
}
```

and compiling it with GCC 7.3.0 via

```
$ g++ -Wall -g -fPIC -shared \
      -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden \
      -o liblibrary.so library.cpp
```

I create a binary which defines a weak symbol for the `operator+()` of a pointer to a character array and a string:

```
$ readelf -sW liblibrary.so | grep "_ZStpl"
    24: 0000000000000ee2   202 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT   12 _ZStplIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIT_T0_T1_EEPKS5_RKS8_
    ...
```

But looking at the standard library binary I got

```
$ readelf -sW /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep "_ZStplIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIT_T0_T1_EEPKS5_RKS8_"
  2829: 000000000012b1c0   169 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT   13 _ZStplIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIT_T0_T1_EEPKS5_RKS8_@@GLIBCXX_3.4.21
```

That's the point where I say: *Oh my gosh,* the symbol inside my library ought to have a version attached to it too!

In the current state I'm fine because I can assume that the standard library binary is built with the same headers as my library. But what happens if the implementers of libstdc++-v3 decide to define a new version of this function and tag it with `GLIBCXX_3.4.22`? Since the symbol is weak, the runtime linker is free to decide whether it takes the unversioned symbol of my library or the versioned symbol of the libstdc++-v3. If I ship my library to such a system I provoke undefined behavior there. Something symbol versions should have solved for me.

Comment: I'm not sure if a discussion about UB makes sense here as you are clearly relying on guarantees by the implementation when shipping the binary. Then, the solution is simply that the gcc/libstdc++ folks promise to not break binary compatibility without announcing it well in advance (gcc5).

Comment: `g++ -Wall -g -fPIC -shared ...` - I think you also need `-Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL`. Otherwise multiple modules may re-export the same symbol. Also see [GCC Issue 87190, Feedback on documentation for symbol visibility](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=87190).

Comment: There is no UB here: You build a single liblibrary.so at which moment there is no ODR violation. The c++ standard does not concern itself with SOs and weak or strong symbols. That's platform specific and outside the scope of the standard.

Comment: @André There is the text and then there is the moral. The moral of the ODR is that all definition of a global name must be strongly equivalent; not only one doesn't care which compiled version of the symbol is used, but so strongly equivalent that one cannot determine which compiled version of the symbol was linked. It means that if you have a class with a static variable, you must ensure that the variable is globally unique OR (you dynamic-load the compiled code such that the all names are changed and made unique AND don't use that class as if it was the same type).